# downgrade to Xcode 6.0.1 is giving compiler error in code

Tags: xcode, swift

I just downgraded from Xcode 6.1.1 to 6.0.1 because in the latest version indexing took way to long and eventually never finished, so I could not run a build of my app. When I downgraded some stuff in my code that was working fine in the 6.1 version received an error in the 6.0.1 version. I have no idea why. This is the code I am talking about

Anyone any idea what could be wrong and how to fix this. The error says "Cannot invoke 'subscript' with an argument list of type CFBundle, etc..

Any help is much appreciated

```
func playPianoButtonSound(button: UIButton) {
    var soundID: SystemSoundID = 0
    let soundURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(
        CFBundleGetMainBundle(), pianoButtonsSoundNames[button], "wav", nil)
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL, &soundID)
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reference "`pianoButtonsSoundNames[button]`" is failing because your UIButton object "`button`" isn't an integer type, and instead should have an integer index (between 0 and whatever).

I suspect that what you really wanted to do here was something like:

"`pianoButtonsSoundNames[button.tag]`"

Comment: Thank You Michael, this code worked fine before though. I changed the code like you said and it is still giving the same issue.